# Find a derivative of an analytic function.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=u + iv$ be analytic. Find $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}|f|^2$.

Not sure since both $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Note that the result can be written in many different ways. Should it be expressed in terms of $u$ and $v$ or in terms of $f$ and its derivatives $f'$, $f''$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $|f|^2$ is a real valued function, as $|f(x,y)|^2=u^2(x,y)+v^2(x,y)$.
To compute the partial derivatives you just need to remember the definition of partial derivative for functions in 2 variables:

$$\frac{\partial|f(x,y)|^2}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial u^2}{\partial y}+
\frac{\partial v^2}{\partial y}=2u\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+2v\frac{\partial v}{\partial y},$$

and similarly for $\frac{\partial^2|f(x,y)|^2}{\partial y^2}$, i.e.

$$\frac{\partial^2|f(x,y)|^2}{\partial y^2}=
2u\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}+2\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2+
2v\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial y^2}+2\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right)^2.
$$

Comment: How would you go about finding f'(x,y)=f'(z)?

Comment: The problem is about the symbol " ' " for functions with complex variables. Even the symbol $f'(x,y)$ on the left is not clear to me: in case of 2 variables, one need to consider partial derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}|f|^2=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}(u^2+v^2)=2\frac{\partial }{\partial y }\left(u\frac{\partial u}{\partial y } +v\frac{\partial v}{\partial y }  \right)$$$$=2u\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2} +2v\frac{\partial^2v}{\partial y^2}+2 \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y }\right)^2+2 \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial y }\right)^2$$